# How do I get a count of and sort a table by frequency of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two different situations in my app that I need the same thing applied. I need to take a table and get an output of how many times a specific record appears. So, for example, I have Users and Users has_many Interactions. An Interaction has_one fb_user. So what I'm trying to do is get a list of users sorted by how many interactions they have. The result should be an array like so:

```
frequency of interactions => list of user ids
1 => [233, 342, 567]
2 => [321 884]
n => [x, y, z]
```

Here's how the models are:

*Interaction Class*

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :fb_user
```

*FbUser Class*

```
class FbUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :interactions
```

then the second situation is similar but instead of getting a list of users, I want to get a list of fb_page_ids. The fb_pages look like this:

*FbPage Class*

```
class FbPage < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :fb_users,
      through: :interactions
   has_many :interactions
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you have written a wring associations check your `Interaction` and `FbUser` model

Comment: @RajarshiDas can you explain? i dont understand what you said

Comment: check the association those are not proper Interaction model `has_one` fb_user